# How do I copy Visio diagrams to Powerpoint in high quality?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-visio, diagrams

Whenever I make Powerpoint presentations, I like to make my diagrams in Visio first, then copy them over to Powerpoint. I'm using Powerpoint 2010 and Visio 2013.

The problem with this is that the diagrams often turn out very low quality. You lose the vector data in this process, and the bitmap really isn't that high resolution. Is there any way to tweak this? If I can't paste the diagrams as vector data, then is there at least a way to have it paste at a higher resolution?

The strange thing is that I don't get this problem when I copy Visio diagrams into MS Word. The diagram gets pasted as an embedded Visio diagram, which effectively means that it gets displayed as vector graphics, and I can edit it inside the word document which is also convenient. This isn't the case for Powerpoint and I can't seem to figure out how to do that.

Comment: What specific versions of Visio and PowerPoint are you using?

Comment: Added the versions to the description (PP 2010 and Visio 2013)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a "feature" of the default paste options in PowerPoint 2010.  If I simply do a ctrl-c ctrl-v from Visio to PowerPoint then I get the behaviour you are seeing

If, on the other hand, I right click and use the paste image button it behaves as you want it to.  The inserted graphic is vector format and resizing is results in absolutely no pixelation. I've shown the button to press below.

[image]

If you want to paste as this kind of image then ctrl-v doesn't seem to cut it. Instead the simplest way I can find it to tap Alt (to bring up the ribbon hotkey system) and then `h`, `v`, and then `u` to just paste it as a picture object (or `s` for special). This will insert it as you expect.  It's a bit longer than ctrl-v, but keeps you on the keyboard rather than using the mouse.

Comment: This works. I can't believe I missed that! Thanks!

Comment: @9a3eedi I couldn't find a way to "fix" the default paste but you can use the ribbon hotkey system instead. `Alt, h, v, u` is the key press series for pasting using the correct format.